# Adding transparency / opacity for images in PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext, opacity

I need to set the opacity for an image and add it to the PDF using iTextSharp. I have looked at the http://itextpdf.com/examples/ but could not find any working examples of doing this.

Can anyone help me or direct me to the right resource.

Answer (score 5):

```
//create new graphics state and assign opacity    
PdfGState graphicsState = new PdfGState();
graphicsState.FillOpacity = 0.2F;  // (or whatever)
//set graphics state to pdfcontentbyte    
pdfData.SetGState(graphicsState);
```